# Regular expression to extract substrings in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex, substring

I have a data frame column name "New" below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'New' : ['emerald shines bright(happy)(ABCED ID - 1234556)', 'honey in the bread(ABCED ID - 123467890)','http/ABCED/id/234555', 'healing strenght(AxYBD ID -1234556)', 'this is just a text'],
'UI': ['AOT', 'BOT', 'LOV', 'HAP', 'NON']})
```

Now I want to extract the various IDs
for example ABCED', AxYBD, and id in the 'http' into another column.

But when I used

```
df['New_col'] = df['New'].str.extract(r'.*\((.*)\).*',expand=True)
```

I can't get it to work well as the whole parenthesis for instance `(ABCED ID - 1234556)` is returned. More so, the http id `234555` is not returned.

Also, can someone clean the first column to removed the ID in paranthesis and have something like,

```
                               New            UI    New_col
0  emerald shines bright(happy)               AOT    1234556
1   honey in the bread                        BOT  123467890
2        http/ABCED/id/234555                 LOV     234555
3        healing strenght                     HAP    1234556
4  this is just a text                        NON
```

Comment: You have to enclose your regex in quotes: `extract(r'.*\((.*)\).*',expand=True)`

Comment: Try `df['New_col'] = df['New'].str.extract(r'.*(?:\(\D*|http\S*/id/)(\d+)',expand=False)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you i go it now. Nick Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Looks like [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74220973/3832970) is yielding the expected output.

Comment: Ok - I have updated my answer to suit your new specifications

Comment: @ScottC running my code gave some errors i realized they are some rows in the dataset that has no Id and should be returned as empty. i modified the code with a w+\s at beginning and still couldn't walk my way arround.

Comment: @Kcndze - have updated my answer to suit your new specifications relating to `text only` lines

Comment: @Kcndze - have updated to deal with the `(happy)` requirement

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most elegant answer, however, I think this does what you want it to do,
 based on the NEW criteria.

```py
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'New' : ['emerald shines bright(happy)(ABCED ID - 1234556)', 'honey in the bread(ABCED ID - 123467890)','http/ABCED/id/234555', 'healing strenght(AxYBD ID -1234556)', 'this is just a text'],
'UI': ['AOT', 'BOT', 'LOV', 'HAP', 'NON']})

def grab_id(row):
    text = re.findall(r'\(([A-Za-z]+)\sID\s-\s?(\d+)\)|/([0-9]+)', row)
    if text:
        if text[0][0]:
            return text[0][1]
        else:
            return text[0][2]
    else:
        return ""
    
    
def remove_ID_in_brackets(row):
    text = re.sub(r'\(([A-Za-z]+)\sID\s-\s?(\d+)\)', '', row)
    
    return text

df['New_Col'] = df['New'].apply(grab_id)
df['New'] = df['New'].apply(remove_ID_in_brackets)
```

This is what **df** looks like now:

[image]

Comment: the raw string works however it didn't return the (happy) in row 0. i.e it extracts all parenthesis. it should only extract the parenthesis with the ID in row 0 as specified in required output.

Comment: @Kcndze - have updated to deal with the `(happy)` requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following code:

```
reg_expression = r'.*\(.*ID\s*-\s*(.*)\)|http\/.*\/id\/(\d*)'
extract_text = lambda row: row[0][0] if row[0][0] else row[0][1]

df['New_col'] = df['New'].str.findall(reg_expression).apply(extract_text)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explaination:**

Based on your dummy example you have to capture two patterns:

- HTTP cases pattern `http\/.*\/id\/(\d*)`

  e.g `http/ABCED/id/234555`
- NO HTTP cases pattern: `.*\(.*ID\s*-\s*(.*)\)`

  e.g `emerald shines bright(ABCED ID - 1234556)`

and combine them in one regex expression by using the or (`|`) operator.

Then because there are multiple matches we can take the value from the match by using a lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'New' : ['emerald shines bright(ABCED ID - 1234556)', 'honey in the bread(ABCED ID - 123467890)','http/ABCED/id/234555', 'healing strenght(AxYBD ID -1234556)'], 'UI': ['AOT', 'BOT', 'LOV', 'HAP']})
df['New_col'] = df['New'].str.extract(r'.*(?:\(\D*|http\S*/id/)(\d+)',expand=False)
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(df.to_string())
                                         New   UI    New_col
0  emerald shines bright(ABCED ID - 1234556)  AOT    1234556
1   honey in the bread(ABCED ID - 123467890)  BOT  123467890
2                       http/ABCED/id/234555  LOV     234555
3        healing strenght(AxYBD ID -1234556)  HAP    1234556
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EXk6Bf/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\(\D*|http\S*/id/)` - either `(` + zero or more non-digit chars, or `http` followed with zero or more non-whitespaces, and then `/id/`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

Answer (score -1):

`r'[i,d,I,D]{2}.*?(\d.*?)\D'` probably this one help

**Edited**: `/?\(?(\w{5}) ?/?[i,d,I,D]{2}` it's looks like you need letters, not digits

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).